# Opening window from secure site domainA.com, to partner site domainB.com - with short TTL encrypted query string

Tags: cryptography, attack-prevention, attack-vector

I am looking into a proposal and need to find reasons as to why we might **not** perform the suggested solution.

Here is the problem:

www.**domain-a**.com is a secure website dealing with customer related functions.

www.**domain-b**.com is a partner website, dealing with a new set of customer related functions that **domain-a**.com is not involved in, other than by way of directing the logged in user to **domain-b**.com upon the user taking a specific journey.

All fine so far, but then we introduce the fact that **domain-a** needs to pass encrypted (confidential) information to **domain-b** via the query string, and this would naturally be an HTTPS GET operation because we are opening a new window.

My question really surrounds the process of encrypting the confidential query string information in the best way possible between **domain-a** and **domain-b** in a way that will reduce or eliminate the possibility of replay, MITM, and other common attacks.

Are there any common patterns for dealing with this kind of scenario, from a cryptography point of view? We would obviously like to ensure that accessed URL's are essentially 'one-shot' - that is, a customer that attempted to copy/bookmark this URL would return to a dead-session/endpoint should they access it again.

I also understand that HTTP GET requests can be cached in IIS/Web infrastructure, and it is not perhaps the **best** way of going about this, but it is the scenario I currently have to deal with, any input would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a side-channel may be a better means of passing the data than trying to pass everything in a query string. The flow would be:

- Domain A sends all relevant data directly to Domain B over HTTPS.
- Domain B stores the data in a temporary session and creates a secure random ID for the session. (Note that this is not a regular session for Domain B, just a temporary list with a very short timeout.)
- Domain B returns the session ID to Domain A.
- Domain A then opens the new window with the URL `https://domain-B/landingpage?tempID=XXXXX`.
- When Domain B receives the token, it removes the matching temporary session and uses the data. If the temp session doesn't exist, then it was a stale URL or a replayed URL and should be handled appropriately.

This way the data is secure because we trust HTTPS, you can pass any amount of data because the side-channel doesn't have query string limitations, there is no need to mess around with encryption keys or similar because HTTPS handles all of that for you, and replay protection is just a natural part of the process.

Comment: Thank you very much, looking into this as a solid option to achieve what we have tasked.

Comment: If it doesn't work, feel free to post a new question with any additional information or requirements. Happy I can help.

Comment: One more thing I have thought of/come across - is it possible to stop someone else from taking this new secure session URL and loading it into their own browser? (Should someone copy and paste the URL for example..)

Comment: Yes @Cmag. If you make the timeout on the temp session short (<5 mins), this will greatly reduce the likelihood that this happens. If that isn't good enough, you can have an iframe from Domain B on your Domain A site that sets a cookie for Domain B. You would then both require the cookie and the session ID. Seems like a lot of work for a problem with a short time window but if it is a problem in your situation, that should fix it.